# How to avoid firing same job by multiple threads in Quartz Schedular?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have configured my job for every one minute. But some times same job get triggered by mutiple threads in milli seconds difference. I am using quartz1.6.

Can anyone help on this?? Also what is the usage of threadPool option in quartz.property file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Spring, you need to set the concurrent property of the Job Detail bean to be false.

Comment: Thanx for your comments. I am not using Spring. Just using Java/J2ee basics with Apache Tomcat web server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
```

Alternatively, you make your job into a Stateful job (and set isClustered to true), and that shoujld solve your problem.
(Oops, StatefulJob is deprecated; use DisallowConcurrentExecution.)